# School Zone Alerts Speed Zone Not Changing / Are the Alerts School Hours Sensitive

Tags: here-api

The speed zone Here.com SDK I am using to best of my knowledge has school zone data included however when ever I driver through a school zone during school hours (as I am of the view the school zone speed zone is time sensitive) It does not change the speed zone as I expect it would.

Also looking at the SDK schoolZoneSpeedLimitInMetersPerSecond.

It does not make any reference to the zones being time of day and day sensitive.

Does that mean that the school zone alerts operate 24/7 if driving through a school zone even though the school is closed eg outside of school hours and on weekends and school holidays.

Comment: I have tested it at several schools the waze app changes to reflect the school zone i am in but the Here SDK data does not

Comment: Can you give one example for such a school? It could be that the data for that school is not there.

Answer (score 0):

The speed limit values for school zones provided by the HERE SDK are sometimes valid based on the current device-time. They are not always time-dependent, and they are notified with the information that is visible on the local road sign.

In your case it seems you see the road sign, but you get no notification. In that case, there may be a data issue and it may be worth to share such places with the HERE team.

Or - it can be that the school zone sign is time-dependent and your device is set to a time outside of that valid time range. Then the notficiation is not forwarded. I am not sure about Waze, but it can be the case that they always forward the limit - even when it is currently not valid, as it's outside the time range.

Comment: So I pose the question, 

When driverless cars start how will the speed zones work as sorry we do not want driverless cars to auto slow down to a speed limit of school zone hours when it’s outside school days / hrs.  Cars with speed sign detection is not the answer as they just read speed value now the school times that appear under the speed value

Comment: I do not see how there is a difference between driverless cars and normal cars for this question. The HERE SDK does not (yet) consume data from speed sign detection cams. All information is stored as part of the map data itself, hence, it also fully supports offline navigation. When the school times are part of the map data, then the SpeedLimitListener should only notify when the current time is in that range - for this, the time of the mobile device is read internally by the HERE SDK. If the mobile device is set to a wrong time, then obviously it would lead to wrong results ...